# After I buy a CA certificate, will I also trust other companys' service certificate which generated from this CA certificate?

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, ca

When I use self-sign certificate, I made a self-CA.cer and a server.cer, server.cer is for web service and self-CA.cer is added in client code. When I check certificate , I check if server.cer is from this self-CA.cer, right?
But, if I buy a CA certificate, what I only got is a server.cer generated from CA, right? and CA certificate can generate many server.cer, and they are all trusted , what I got is one from these . 
In my client code, others said I only need to change my http to https, that's it ,after I buy CA. but how can I distinguish which server certificate is from my own server? I only want trust the server certificate from my own server.

Answer (score 0):

> if I buy a CA certificate

you can't buy a CA certificate (with small exception, which is not your case). You are purchasing an end-entity certificate which cannot be used to sign other certificates. It is controlled by a `Basic Constraints` certificate. Any standard validation code will reject any certificate that is signed by non-CA certificate due to Basic Constraints extension value (`isCA` attribute is set to `False`).

[RFC 5280 -- Basic Constraints](http://Basic%20Constraints)

Comment: OP fairly clearly means a server/EE cert _from_ a 'real' (public, established) CA. Quote: 'I only got ... server.cer [i.e. EE cert, not a root cert as with DIY] ... from CA'

Answer (score 0):

If you trust a CA you trust all certs they issue (unless expired or revoked) -- that's how PKI works.

If that CA issues certs to other sites/servers, *and* you make HTTPS (or otherwise SSL/TLS or DTLS) connections to those *other* sites/severs, you will trust their certs and thus trust them.

But if you mean you want to trust only the specific cert issued to your server *for your server*, that's automatic. The cert issued to your server has your domain name in it, while the certs issued to other servers have their (different) names, and an HTTPS client like a browser will only trust a cert that is issued by a trusted CA *and* has the correct server name in it, so it will trust only your cert for your server, and will trust other certs only for the other servers those certs are issued to.

For much more detail, see Stack's Great Ursine Epic https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-work/